# Installing Ubuntu in VBox (Windows 10)?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-10, virtualization

Windows 10 is on computer.

I am using Oracle VBox. I used the recommended setting (8GB size for Ubuntu and selected ISO from my computer). Ubuntu has options to try without installing and to install. If I install it (it fits in the size VBOx reccomended) will Windows 10 be uninstalled (will my disk be wiped)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight answer **No**

The virtual box creates a virtual hard drive meaning that anything that happens to that virtual HD will not happen to the host machine.

You could say:
What happens in the virtual machine stays in the virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was hoping, since it seemed to be the point of VM.